# Apply isotope data-filter on page load

Tags: wordpress, jquery-isotope

I have a WordPress plugin which uses isotope data-filter to sort the menu items, but on page load the items are not categorized. I added the following function to my functions.php:

```
function add_custom_script(){
?>
<script>
(function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('a[data-filter=".sparmenue"]').trigger('click');
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_custom_script');
```

It does the job, but it's ugly because it's executed after the items were initially displayed. I read other post here about similar problems, but I can't get the solutions to work for my specific template.

[Demo page](http://dpc.timonster.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a wildcard filter to get all items?

```
<a href="#" data-filter="*" class="menu-filter-link">Alle anzeigen</a>
```

**Edit:** OK i think you dont need all the items on the first menu. So here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/DA3wF/) Showing exactly what you need.

**EDIT: Just replace this code at the end of your file**

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('a[data-filter=".sparmenue"]').trigger('click');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**With this one**

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#grid-wrap'),
      $filterLinks = $('#menu-filters a');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
    filter: '.sparmenue'
  });

  $filterLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return;
    }

    $filterLinks.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // get selector from data-filter attribute
    selector = $this.data('filter');

    $container.isotope({
      filter: selector
    });


  });

});
```

**If you want you can also add a selected class next to menu-filter-link to highlight the selected category.**

Comment: Hi Omer, sorry i dont understand. I already got all items on page load but what i want is the data filter with certain category applied on page load instead of all images being displayed.

Comment: Ok i have added a jsfiddle in my answer that does exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for that, i understand how it works in principle but not how to add it to my template:[link](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3716)
my js looks like this:[link](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3717)

Comment: Hi Omer Thank you very much for your support ! The code seems not to work unfortunately. I have uploaded the full template file to avoid mistakes  by me inserting the code:[link](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3727)

Comment: Did you try adding class="menu-filter-link selected" to the anchor of "Alle anzeigen"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using option sets?

```
   var $container = [$('#container-menu'), $('#container-bar'), $('#container-specials')], $optionSets = [$('#option-menu .option-set'), $('#option-bar .option-set'), $('#option-specials .option-set')];

 //initialize isotope on each container
    jQuery.each($container, function (j) {
        this.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.menu-item',
           // filter:'.First',
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: '.menu-item'
                }
            });
        });

    //initialize filter links for each option set
    jQuery.each($optionSets, function (index, object) {

        var $optionLinks = object.find('a');

        $optionLinks.click(function () {
            var $this = $(this), $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set'), options = {},
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
            // don't proceed if already selected
                if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
                    return false;
                }

        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');

        // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }

        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[key] = value;
            if (key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function') {
                // changes in layout modes need extra logic
                changeLayoutMode($this, options);
            } else {
        // otherwise, apply new options

            $container[index].isotope(options);
            }

                return false;
                });
            });
        });


``
```